# How to get the number of the Subarray with at least K different numbers?

Tags: algorithm, sub-array

The question is:
"Given an array A only contains integers Return the number of subarrays that contain at least k different numbers. Subarrays cannot be duplicated."

Example:

```
input array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 2} k = 3

output: 4
```

Explanation:

the number of the Subarray with at least K different numbers should be 4,
which are [1, 2, 3] [2, 3, 4] [3, 4, 2] [1, 2, 3, 4]

Right now what I can do is just find about the number of the subarray with exactly K different numbers:

```
class Solution {
    public int subarraysWithKDistinct(int[] A, int K) {
        return atMostK(A, K) - atMostK(A, K - 1);
    }
    
    private int atMostK(int[] A, int K) {
        int i = 0, res = 0;
        
        Map<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
        
        for (int j = 0; j < A.length; ++j) {
            
            if (count.getOrDefault(A[j], 0) == 0) K--;
            count.put(A[j], count.getOrDefault(A[j], 0) + 1);
            
            while (K < 0) {
                count.put(A[i], count.get(A[i]) - 1);
                if (count.get(A[i]) == 0) K++;
                i++;
            
            }
            res += j - i + 1;
        }
        
        return res;
    }
}
```

But when the input be:
array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 2} k = 2
my code will not work correctly, but I don't know where to change. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Update: thanks to @MBo and others' answers, I used 2 pointers to fix this problem, but still cannot get the right answer with:
array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 2} k = 3 -> output: 6 (should be 4)

It looks like there are some duplicated substrings be counted, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 2};
        int k = 3;
        int res = helper(A, k);
        System.out.println(res);
        // output is 6, but should be 4
    }
    
    private static int helper(int[] A, int k) {
        if (A == null || A.length == 0) return 0;
    
        int n = A.length;
        int res = 0;
        int differentNumbers = 0;

        Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
        int j = 0;  // j - 1 is the right point


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
            while (j < n && differentNumbers < k) {
                int numOfThisNumber = counter.getOrDefault(A[j], 0);
                counter.put(A[j], numOfThisNumber + 1);
                if (counter.get(A[j]) == 1) {
                    differentNumbers ++;
                }
                j ++;
            }
            if (differentNumbers == k) {
                res += n - j + 1;
            }

            counter.put(A[i], counter.get(A[i]) - 1);
            if (counter.get(A[i]) == 0) {
                differentNumbers --;
            }
        }
        return res; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Try computing the number of such subarrays *that end at position i*, for each i. These can be added together without double-counting or missing solutions.

Comment: The count should actually be 5, since {1,2,3,4,2} is a subarray of itself and does contain 3 unique numbers, unless you add the condition that subarrays contain no duplicate values.

In that case, the result is computable with simple binomial coefficients:

let `u` be the number of unique values, your result is the sum of all arrangements of `k` to `u` items drawn from a set of length u, i.e. the sum of `(i!)/((i-k!)(k!))` for `i` in `[k..u]`

If you count duplicates, then your example should include {1,2,3,4,2} in the list and the expected result should be corrected.

Comment: Emm... Statement `Subarray with at least K different numbers` does not claim that duplicate values are not allowed inside subarray. Could you show exact problem formulation?

Comment: Sure, sorry about the unclear question. I also updated the topic. The question is "Given an array A only contains integers
Return the number of subarrays that contain at least k different numbers. Subarrays cannot be duplicated." It is my professor's in-class pop-quiz last week, and I tried to look up leetcode or hackerrank, cannot find similar problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine your hashmap approach with method of two pointers (indices).

Set both indices into 0 and move `right` one, updating hashmap counts for values at the `right` end of interval until hashmap size reaches `K`. Fix `right` index.

Now move `left` index, decreasing counts corresponding to the values at `left` end. Before every step (including `left=0`) add `size-right` to result, because **all** subarrays starting from `left` and ending after `right`, do contain needed number of elements.

When some count becomes `0`, remove value from hashmap, and fix `left` index.

Repeat with `right` index and so on.